# Matching Column name from Csv file in spark scala

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark

I want to take headers (column name) from my csv file and the want to match with it my existing header.
I am using below code:

```
val cc = sparksession.read.csv(filepath).take(1)
```

Its giving me value like:

```
Array([id,name,salary])
```

and I have created one more static schema, which is giving me value like this:

```
val ss=Array("id","name","salary")
```

and then I'm trying to compare column name using if condition:

```
if(cc==ss){
  println("matched")
} else{
  println("not matched")
}
```

I guess due to `[]` and `()` mismatch its always going to else part is there any other way to compare these value without considering `[]` and `()`?

Comment: Try with a.deep == b.deep for a deep comparison

Comment: Do you only want to compare column names or their values as well?

Answer (score 4):

First, for convenience, set the header option to true when reading the file:

```
val df = sparksession.read.option("header", true).csv(filepath)
```

Get the column names and define the expected column names:

```
val cc = df.columns
val ss = Array("id", "name", "salary")
```

To check if the two match (not considering the ordering):

```
if (cc.toSet == ss.toSet) {
  println("matched")
} else {
  println("not matched")
}
```

If the order is relevant, then the condition can be done as follows (you can't use `Array` here but `Seq` works):

```
cc.toSeq == ss.toSeq
```

or you a deep array comparison:

```
cc.deep == d.deep
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I think you are trying to compare a `Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]` with an `Array[String]`. I believe you should change how you load the headers to something like: `val cc = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").load(fileName).columns.toArray`.
Then you could compare using cc.deep == ss.deep.

Comment: val cc= spark.read.csv("filepath").take(1)(0).toString and then cretaed ss as ("","")after that applied if condition. Will try  your solution also. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Below code worked for me.

```
val cc= spark.read.csv("filepath").take(1)(0).toString
```

The above code gave output as String:[id,name,salary].

created one one stating schema as

```
val ss="[id,name,salary]"
```

then wrote the if else Conditions.